# Liquibase grails application does not start after upgrade

Tags: grails, liquibase

I upgraded my grails version from 3.8 to 4. In this step I upgraded the liquibase to 3.10.1.
Now my application won't startup any more. I get an error on this changeset:

```
changeSet(author: "prog1", id: "httpconnector-add-ignoreSSLVerification") {
        addColumn(tableName: "inbound_connector") {
            column(name: "ignoresslverification ", type: "boolean")
        }
        addColumn(tableName: "outbound_connector") {
            column(name: "ignoresslverification ", type: "boolean")
        }
        sql("UPDATE outbound_connector set ignoresslverification  = true")
        sql("UPDATE inbound_connector set ignoresslverification  = true")
    }
```

I get this error:

```
liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set migrations/changelog.groovy::httpconnector-add-ignoreSSLVerification::ff:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: column "ignoresslverification" of relation "outbound_connector" does not exist
  Position: 31 [Failed SQL: (0) UPDATE outbound_connector set ignoresslverification  = true]
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error: There is a blank at at column name. The old version ignored this, but the new version not.